Copy Visual Studio project settings into another project (VS 2022)
(Apologies, I know this question has been asked a number of times but I'm struggling to see something specific for VS 2022, which seems to have changed things regarding my question)
As per the title, I'm trying to use Property Manager to create a property sheet from a project I've set up, in order to easily import those properties into any new project. I've been trying to follow...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-170
This seems very straightforward but I can't get it to work for me.
I have the Property Manager opened as follows...

I right mouse click on the "Release x64" configuration, for example, and select 'Add New Project Property Sheet', give it a name and location to save, then click 'Add' to save the sheet. A new entry then appears under "Release x64" with the property sheet name I chose.
I can see the .props file created at the location I chose but opening it in notepad++ seems to show very little, almost like it's missing the crucial config data.
I then tested that file out on a new empty project and used the 'Add Existing Property Sheet...' function to bring in that same file, after which, I could also see added as a new entry. Unfortunately, the include and lib files etc were not set in the relevant project config pages.
It seems like while I can create a new .props sheet, it seems to be empty. I'd be grateful if someone could help with what I should be doing here...there's something obvious that my brain is having problems with, lol.
[Edit]
I found out where I was going wrong. I started off with a project where I had configured everything (include files, libs etc for Debug and Release) before creating a properties sheet. I then created a test property sheet in Property Manager, falsely assuming it would capture/pre-populate all the customisations I made for that project...
In fact, to get this to work, for each property sheet you create you must right mouse click on that new property sheet entry you created, and configure everything there. It starts off as a 100% blank sheet...waiting on you to configure it.
Importing that property sheet into another, new project will have that project use your customisations for the build/s you're needing (e.g. separate property sheets for for Debug and Release).
Once I figured out how to do this, I do like it. It does everything needed, in an easy to use way, to transfer properties from one project to another. It just takes a little getting used to. Additionally, you can easily change these sheets in notepad if needed...which might frequently be much easier and faster.
I still thing that Microsoft doc I linked to could be a bit more helpful.

Did you also do a "Save All" from the File menu? (Ctrl-Shift-S) -- the property sheet should have an entry in your .vcxproj file with the <Import ...> tag. I personally never use the UI for messing with property sheets, preferring to edit the project file (and properties) in a text editor.

On second read of your question, you say that you're not seeing the includes and libs (from the property sheet) in your project config. That's expected behavior. They are hidden in the project properties. If you want to see those, you need to right-click and choose "Properties" from the property sheet in the Property Manager, not the main project config.

Thanks for your reply paddy. I did do a "Save All" from the File menu but unfortunately that didn't make a difference. The steps I took create the property sheet from that microsoft link I included above resulted in a single .props file at the location I specified. Should this single file not hold all the configuration data? It doesn't seem to when I load it into an empty new project - the custom config data is definitely not there when I right mouse click the Property Sheet and choose "Properties", or in the route provided when right mouse clicking the project itself in the Solution Explorer.

I figured out where I was going wrong here (see updated question)
